# Kubernetes flanneld VXLAN control plane

Tags: kubernetes, vxlan

I want to build a kubernetes cluster, but it's unclear where or how I configure the flannel VXLAN control plane.

I know that `flanneld` typically uses a UDP VXLAN data-plane encapsulation; however, does `flanneld` use BGP for the VXLAN control plane?  Is this configurable?  If so, what yaml options configure it?  If it's not BGP, how are the other kubernetes nodes VXLAN bindings learned?

FYI, even if you don't know how to configure it, I'm happy just to know what the default `flanneld` VXLAN control-plane is.